# How can I remove the root path when creating a zip archive from a directory?

Tags: php, path, zip

I am making a zip-archive from directory `mydir` stored in `/my/files/inside/here/`.

I want the archive `mydir.zip` to contain only the files and dirs from `mydir`.
The problem, however, is that i now get the full rooth path `/my/files/inside/here/mydir/` when I unzip..

```
    $mypath = "/my/files/inside/here/";
    $dirname_to_zip = "mydir";

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipfile_with_path = $mypath.$dirname_to_zip.".zip";

    if ($zip->open($zipfile_with_path, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) 
        die("failed to create zip");

    // Create recursive directory iterator
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($mydir.$dirname_to_zip),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file)
    {
        // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
        if (!$file->isDir())
        {
            // Get real and relative path for current file
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($dirname_to_zip) );

            // Add current file to archive
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        }
    }

    $zip->close();
```

How can I remove the root path?